# How to downgrade from Bootstrap 4 to 3 in Laravel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, laravel-5.6, adminlte

I have searched on google but could not found any useful link. 
I am integrating AdminLTE with laravel 5.6 and AdminLTE needs bootstrape 3 and laravel have 4. 
So, I want to downgrade to Bootstrape 3 from 4.

Answer (score 3):

if anyone just needed this.

Here are the steps:

```
1. Npm install bootstrap@3.3.7
2. Change the bootstrap entry from package.json and replace it with "bootstrap": "3.3.7"
3. in resources/assets/sass/app.scss,
        a. comment out the import of variables 
           OR change height base to 14 px instead of 0.9 rem in _variable.scss. 
        b. change the path of bootstrap to 
           @import "node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap";
4. in resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js, 
   look for require('bootsrap-sass'); and change it to require('bootstrap');
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap.

Comment: it works for me. For sure also add:  
1.1. npm install bootstrap-sass
1.2 copy fonts folder from node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/fonts/ to node_modules/bootstrap-sass/assets/stylesheets/fonts/ 
5. run npm run dev